# Create 2 Cloud Functions for 1 project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

How do I create 2 Cloud Functions for 1 project? Currently, I'm only able to deploy one.

Answer (score 1):

No you can deploy  many Fuctions

Your index.js

```
 exports.firstfunction= functions.database
.ref('').onWrite(event => {
 };
exports.secondfunction= functions.database
.ref('').onWrite(event => {
 }
```

Comment: Do they run at the same time?

Comment: Or one starts after the other?

Comment: Functions works with specific condition 
Not sequence

Comment: I tried this today. It doesn't work with me. I still can't add 2 functions... Currently, I only see one function in my dashboard. Is something missing in your answer?