# Can't add 2 Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

*This is supposed to be an easy task. I'm so amazed by how much time I spent investigating the issue...*

I have this Cloud Function in my `index.js`:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/messaging/{pushId}')
.onWrite(event => {
    //do something      
});
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45899970/8458857) answer, I can simply add a second Function like so:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.myFunction= functions.database.ref('/messaging/{pushId}').onWrite(event => { //do something }); 

exports.secondFunction= functions.database.ref('/messaging/{pushId}').onWrite(event => {//do something });
```

But, in my Firebase Dashboard, there's still one Function listed: `myFunction`. Did I miss something? How can I add 2 Cloud Functions properly?

Comment: There is a double single quote after `{pushId}` in `myFunction`. So your complete secondFunction is in a string.

Comment: That was just an example. I'll fix it

Comment: Can you show the output of the `firebase deploy --only functions` command?

Comment: I'm gonna do it soon, Frank. Please be patient. Thanks!

Comment: Never mind. I fixed the issue.